# Filtering array of objects with lodash based on property value

Tags: javascript, filter, filtering, lodash

We have an array of objects as such

```
var myArr = [ {name: "john", age: 23},
              {name: "john", age: 43},
              {name: "jim", age: 101},
              {name: "bob", age: 67} ];
```

how do I get the list of objects from myArr where name is john with lodash?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Lodash has a "map" function that works just like jQuerys:

```js
var myArr =  [{ name: "john", age:23 },
              { name: "john", age:43 },
              { name: "jimi", age:10 },
              { name: "bobi", age:67 }];

var johns = _.map(myArr, function(o) {
    if (o.name == "john") return o;
});

// Remove undefines from the array
johns = _.without(johns, undefined)
```

Comment: thank you but I asked specifically lodash answer. I can do a loop myself.

Comment: I removed irrelevant answer and fixed your script  as it had errors in it

Comment: lodash _.filter method is the most correct answer as it does what the OP asks w.o step of removing undefines.

Comment: 'Johns' or 'JOHNS'  what should I do? The result still returns the 'johns' is okay

Answer (score 152):

Use lodash `_.filter` method:

```
_.filter(collection, [predicate=_.identity])
```

Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all elements predicate returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with three arguments:
(value, index|key, collection).

**with predicate as custom function**

```
 _.filter(myArr, function(o) { 
    return o.name == 'john'; 
 });
```

**with predicate as part of filtered object** (the `_.matches` iteratee shorthand)

```
_.filter(myArr, {name: 'john'});
```

**with predicate as [key, value] array** (the `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.)

```
_.filter(myArr, ['name', 'John']);
```

Docs reference: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter

Comment: You should mention that your example using _.matchesProperty iteratee shorthand works only from lodash v4. For lodash v3 it's without the array brackets.

Answer (score 16):

#### With [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
const myArr = [ {name: "john", age: 23},
                {name: "john", age: 43},
                {name: "jim", age: 101},
                {name: "bob", age: 67} ];

const johnArr = _.filter(myArr, person => person.name === 'john');
console.log(johnArr)
```

[image]

#### Vanilla JavaScript:

```
const myArr = [ {name: "john", age: 23},
                {name: "john", age: 43},
                {name: "jim", age: 101},
                {name: "bob", age: 67} ];

const johnArr = myArr.filter(person => person.name === 'john');
console.log(johnArr);
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Filter by name, age **
also, you can use the map function

> **difference between map and filter**

**1. map** - The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element. The map method allows items in an array to be manipulated to the user’s preference, returning the conclusion of the chosen manipulation in an entirely new array. For example, consider the following array:

**2. filter** - The filter() method creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test implemented by the provided function. The filter method is well suited for particular instances where the user must identify certain items in an array that share a common characteristic. For example, consider the following array:

```
const users = [
    { name: "john", age: 23 },
    { name: "john", age:43 },
    { name: "jim", age: 101 },
    { name: "bob", age: 67 }
];

const user = _.filter(users, {name: 'jim', age: 101});
console.log(user);
```

Comment: You're missing your example for #1.

Answer (score 5):

```
let myArr = [
    { name: "john", age: 23 },
    { name: "john", age: 43 },
    { name: "jim", age: 101 },
    { name: "bob", age: 67 },
];

let list = _.filter(myArr, item => item.name === "john");
```

Comment: This worked for me, why people downvoted this, is there any problem with this solution?

Comment: @Arman maybe they are didn't like this way of getting a result. There are many ways how we can do it. But this one also good

Comment: @NverAbgaryan  - Same as above, how to apply key dynamically ?

Answer (score 5):

```js
let myArr = [
    { name: "john", age: 23 },
    { name: "john", age: 43 },
    { name: "jim", age: 101 },
    { name: "bob", age: 67 },
];

// this will return old object (myArr) with items named 'john'
let list = _.filter(myArr, item => item.name === 'jhon');

//  this will return new object referenc (new Object) with items named 'john' 
let list = _.map(myArr, item => item.name === 'jhon').filter(item => item.name);
```

Comment: Have in mind that answers containing only code are not considered complete

Comment: let list = _.filter(myArr, item => item.name === 'jhon');
instead of "item.name" here name is statically placed, if it is dynamic key, how to write ?

Answer (score 1):

lodash also has a remove method

```
var myArr = [
    { name: "john", age: 23 },
    { name: "john", age: 43 },
    { name: "jim", age: 101 },
    { name: "bob", age: 67 }
];

var onlyJohn = myArr.remove( person => { return person.name == "john" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this to combine filter with an includes to see if the option includes a specific string (answerQuery in this case)

```
  return filter(answerOptions, (option) => {
    return includes(option.label.toLowerCase(), answerQuery.toLowerCase());
  });
```