# How to filter array on any matching value using lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

So I have objects that I want to be able to search for any matches of values.

For example:

```
let arr = [
    {
        a: 'foo',
        b: 'bar'
    },
    {
        a: 'bar',
        b: 'baz'
    },
    {
        a: 'foo',
        b: 'baz'
    }
];
```

and I want to be able to filter the array to contain any object that has a property with the value 'foo'.

Is there a way to do this with lodash? Something like:

```
_.filter(arr, function(obj) {
    return obj.anyPropertiesMatch('bar');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering array of objects with lodash based on property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182904/filtering-array-of-objects-with-lodash-based-on-property-value)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.filter()` and check if the value exists, using `Object.values()` to get an array of values, and `Array.includes()` to check if they include `val`:

```js
const val = 'foo';

const arr = [{"a":"foo","b":"bar"},{"a":"bar","b":"baz"},{"a":"foo","b":"baz"}];

const result = arr.filter((o) => Object.values(o).includes(val));

console.log(result);
```

Or the lodash's equivalent using [`_.includes()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#includes):

```js
const val = 'foo';

const arr = [{"a":"foo","b":"bar"},{"a":"bar","b":"baz"},{"a":"foo","b":"baz"}];

const result = _.filter(arr, (o) => _.includes(o, val));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that both arrow functions and `Object.values` will likely require the code to be transpiled to ES5.

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as this:

`_.filter(arr, o=>_.includes(o,'foo'));`

you can use lodash array function to any object directly and it will consider each values against each elements.

Here is an working example for you:

```js
let arr = [
    {
        a: 'foo',
        b: 'bar'
    },
    {
        a: 'bar',
        b: 'baz'
    },
    {
        a: 'foo',
        b: 'baz'
    }
];

let res = _.filter(arr, o=>_.includes(o,'foo'));
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In lodash, you can use `some` method to validate that object has the field with the provided value:

```js
let arr = [
  { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' },
  { a: 'bar', b: 'baz' },
  { a: 'foo', b: 'baz' }
];

let result = _.filter(arr, obj => _.some(obj, val => val === 'foo'));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LoDash `_.filter` to filter the array based on object values, gotten with `_.values` and checked with `_.includes`

```js
let arr = [
    {
        a: 'foo',
        b: 'bar'
    },
    {
        a: 'bar',
        b: 'baz'
    },
    {
        a: 'foo',
        b: 'baz'
    }
];

let res = _.filter(arr, o => _.includes(_.values(o), 'foo'));

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```