# filter an array of objects by property based on where like condition

Tags: angular, lodash

I need to filter an array of objects where specific property matches what user has type.

given this

```
peopleList = [ 
  {name: "john bee", age:23},
  {name: "john woo", age:43},
  {name: "jim foo", age:101},
  {name: "bob wow", age:67},
  {name: "last john", age:43},
]
```

As soon as the user types the first character I would like to filter the array based not on exact match but on what "where like".

I've check this question:
[Filtering array of objects with lodash based on property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182904/filtering-array-of-objects-with-lodash-based-on-property-value/35183271)

but it returns only one exact match or nothing.

What lodash function can I use to return an array of objects where name property matched the query string entered by the user so that if user types 'Jo' this is returned:

```
[ 
  {name: "john bee", age:23},
  {name: "john woo", age:43},
  {name: "last john", age:43},
]
```

I am using Angular if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
const peopleList = [ 
  {name: "john bee", age:23},
  {name: "john woo", age:43},
  {name: "jim foo", age:101},
  {name: "bob wow", age:67},
  {name: "last john", age:43},
]
const search = "jo"

cosnt subList = peopleList.filter((person)=>person.name.indexOf(search) > -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In es6 syntax it look like

```
const filteredArray = peopleList.filter( people => people.name.includes(someText) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working snippet without lodash and plain javascript :

```js
var peopleList = [ 
  {name: "john bee", age:23},
  {name: "john woo", age:43},
  {name: "jim foo", age:101},
  {name: "bob wow", age:67},
  {name: "last john", age:43},
];

var result = peopleList.filter(person => person.name.includes("jo"));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can I use this inside .ts files? The large project I am working on is based on typescript, not my decision. If above cant be used what is alternative?

Comment: Yes why not , you can use that without any doubts @nikocraft

Comment: Can I just add a suggestion, to make this more like an actual `where like` condition, to do the filter on `person.name.toLowerCase()` as `includes()` is case sensitive, although in this specific case, since all the names are lower cased, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: great suggestion, jun where do I throw in this suggestion considering above code by vivek?