# how do i find and return a specific object key and return as array in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

how do I find and return a specific object key and return as array in lodash.

```
const category = [
 { id: 123, name: "haha"},
 { id: 124, name: "haha2"},
 { id: 125, name: "haha3"},
]
```

how do i get this?
result: [123,124,125]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering array of objects with lodash based on property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182904/filtering-array-of-objects-with-lodash-based-on-property-value)

Answer (score 0):

make for each loop to iterate over category and each element of category has id push it into empty arr

```
let result = []

const category = [
    { id: 123, name: "haha"},
    { id: 124, name: "haha2"},
    { id: 125, name: "haha3"},
   ]

category.forEach(c=>{
    result.push(c.id)
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Array.map:

category.map(item => item.id)